# mysqldump to Postgres (Specific table)

Tags: postgresql, mysql

I can dump my db with those codes:

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u username --password=MyPassword --port 3306 --single-transaction --routines \
--triggers --databases my_database --compress  --compact --compatible=postgresql \
--default-character-set=utf8 > my_database.mysql
```

but I want to dump specific table from my database with that code. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables), you should use --tables tablename to dump a specific table. It overrides the --databases setting.